# IDEA 2018.2 how to clear debug condition history

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I have an obsessive quality to me... anybody who can tell me how to clear the debug condition records in idea-2018.2?

[image]

Comment: Inline the picture.

Comment: You could search ".idea/workspace.xml" for <expressions id="breakpointCondition> element and remove unneded items.

Comment: thanks a lot.Cured my obsessive-compulsive disorder.haha、